# query with join that count id of column and also count that id on behalf of particular value arrange both by year and month

Tags: sql-server

This is the DB structure

[image]

```
USE [Fiefo]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[practicefunc]    Script Date: 05/24/2017 16:46:37 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER function [dbo].[practicefunc]
(@startdate varchar(50), @enddate varchar(50), @userid varchar(50))
Returns Table
As
Return(select count(Activity.act_id) as TotalActivities ,count(Contact.c_id) as TotalContact ,
MONTH(Activity.added_on) as [Month],
       Year(Activity.added_on) as [Year]
from Activity
INNER JOIN Contact
ON Activity.ref_id=Contact.c_id 

WHERE   Activity.added_on >= @startdate and Activity.added_on <= @enddate
AND     Activity.added_by = @userid

GROUP BY  MONTH(Activity.added_on),Year(Activity.added_on))
```

Result of this query is :

[image]

Now i want to add another column of follow up that count activity -act_id  where category='add follow up' and arrange count according to month and year .
how can I achieve this ?

Comment: edit your code using ctrl+k then write query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compute a column of 1 or 0 with your filter, and sum this column, like this:

```
select count(Activity.act_id) as TotalActivities ,count(Contact.c_id) as TotalContact , MONTH(Activity.added_on) as [Month], Year(Activity.added_on) as [Year], 
sum(CASE WHEN Activity.category = 'add follow up' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ComputedColumn
from Activity INNER JOIN Contact ON Activity.ref_id=Contact.c_id

WHERE Activity.added_on >= @startdate and Activity.added_on <= @enddate AND Activity.added_by = @userid

GROUP BY MONTH(Activity.added_on),Year(Activity.added_on)
```

Comment: its help full but i want to count actid  like select count act id from activity and select count act id from activity where category is equal to follow up

Comment: Sorry for my english, but, wath do you mean with category equals follow up? Is there a category called 'follow up'? If that is the case, you can't put that criteria in the where statement, because it will filter ALL your rows. When I used the CASE statemen it will count all your rows with that category without filtering the rows. What is wrong with that?

Comment: category is the column in activity table that have to in which one is 'addfollowup'. so i want to count(act_id)  and groupby month year . and also again count(act_id) groupby month year where category='addfollowup' .so that in a month how many addfollowup

Comment: the query i wrote solves that for you, did you tested it??